# Using md5 on BeautifulSoup result

Tags: python, md5, beautifulsoup

Im trying to use the md5 algorithm on web pages to avoid seeing duplicates. Is there an easy way to convert the result from beautifulsoup into a string which is digestible by md5?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just turn it into a string with `str`:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
doc = "<html><h1>Heading</h1><p>Text"
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)

str(soup)
```

(from [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Printing%20a%20Document))